# Could not find configuration file (pubspec.yaml) on windows

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, pubspec.yaml

I'm using flutter with Dart on AndoidStudio, tried to add image to my app and to do so I need to
find pubspec.yaml file so that I can add image directory but the problem is that there is no pubspec.yaml file in my project files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anhgt.png)

Comment: It should be in the folder above your android folder, like in [this image](https://www.tilcode.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Screenshot-2020-05-03-19.56.07-634x1024.png).

Answer (score 1):

the image you uploaded shows your android folder. Open your project folder which will contain pubspec.yaml file along android, ios folder etc.
[image: should look something like this]